# How to make Docker Compose pull & restart when any of the image is updated?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I make my docker compose restart itself and use the latest image (pulls new version of the image) when any of its images has a new push? Thanks!

Comment: By using docker-compse down then pull then up -d ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `docker-compose`. There is the need for something/someone who checks for new image, something like [Watchtower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/), for example.